# Trying to instal lxml ? Looks like nothing is getting install in my system?

Tags: python, ubuntu

My system configuration :

---

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.10
Release:    16.10
Codename:   yakkety

> Terminal~$sudo apt-get install python-lxml

```
Error Found :
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dkms libgsoap9 libvncserver1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python-bs4 python-chardet python-html5lib
Suggested packages:
  python-genshi python-lxml-dbg python-lxml-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python-bs4 python-chardet python-html5lib python-lxml
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 782 kB/962 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,173 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Ign:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 python-bs4 all 4.5.1-1
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main amd64 python-lxml amd64 3.6.4-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/main i386 python-bs4 all 4.5.1-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/b/beautifulsoup4/python-bs4_4.5.1-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lxml/python-lxml_3.6.4-1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Why not `pip install lxml?` Also, do be aware Ubuntu come pre-loaded with python 2. To install modules in python 3, run: `python3 -m pip install lxml`. Might have to `sudo` for various folder access and system privileges.

Comment: it worked thanks.@Parfait

Comment: Generally speaking, `apt` looking for files that don't exist means you haven't run an `apt-get update` (to refresh the listing of which packages are located where) recently enough. That said, questions about `apt-get` failing aren't exclusively development-centric, are might in the future be a better fit for [ubuntu.se].